# Boolean difference modifier not working on a custom mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to cut away a curved part inside a custom mesh with the help of a cylinder but the boolean modifier doesn't seems to work, When I try it with another  inbuilt meshes it works I have applied the boolean modifier on the custom mesh and then selected the cylinder for boolean[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: I think Andrew's anvil and donuts give us the most of our work here... (just a little comment as it is in comments... ; )

Comment: Concretely, you should add some picture of your modifier settings or upload your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'ts a default boolean modifier with difference and cylinder selected as object

Comment: Sometimes, boolean fails. Is the cylinder close shape? Have you tried to change its threshold a bit? Again if you could upload the file that could be fast to know.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the file

Comment: You have doubled vertices into the anvil: go in edit mode for the anvil, select all and alt+m to merge by distance.

Comment: Thanks, It worked!

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming Blender 2.80)
The anvil has a defect geometry. To fix this, select the anvil, go edit mode.
Then "Merge Vertice->By Distance" and leave Edit mode. Then it looks like this:
[image: Andrews Curse ;)]

PS: I switched the cylinder into "Wire" display...